# Form validation not working in angularjs

Tags: php, jquery, angularjs, forms, validation

Here is my form validation. Only the password match and required is working. But the firstname and email validation is not working.

**The email validation is not working**

```
<input placeholder="Email" class="text_box1" type="text" name="email" ng-model="signup.email"  style="width:236px;">
<span class="errorMessage"  ng-show="signupForm.email.$error.email" class="help-inline">Email is not valid</span> 
<span class="errorMessage"  ng-show="signupForm.email.$error.required" class="help-inline">Email is required.</span>
```

**The password validation is working good**

```
<input placeholder="Password" class="text_box1" type="text" name = "password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="signup.password"  style="width:236px;">
<small class="errorMessage" data-ng-show="signupForm.password.$dirty && signupForm.password.$invalid"> Enter Password.</small>
<input placeholder="Confirm Password" class="text_box1" type="text"  name="password2" placeholder="Password Again" ng-model="signup.password2" password-match="signup.password"  style="width:236px;">
<small class="errorMessage" data-ng-show="signupForm.password2.$dirty && signupForm.password2.$error.required"> Enter password again.</small>
<small class="errorMessage" data-ng-show="signupForm.password2.$dirty && signupForm.password2.$error.passwordNoMatch && !signupForm.password2.$error.required"> Password do not match.</small>
```

I am disabling the button by default and making it valid only if the form is valid, but due to the above issue, once the password validation works the button is enabled.

```
<button class="sign_up" ng-click="doReg()" data-ng-disabled="signupForm.$invalid">Sign up</button>
```

**How can i make the email validation work, so that the button will be enabled only after email validation is satisfied. ?**

**Note :** I aim for the required and valid email validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `type="text"` to `type="email"` of your email input.

**E.g.**

```
<input type="email" 
   name="email" 
   ng-model="signup.email"  
   placeholder="Email" 
   class="text_box1" 
   style="width:236px;" 
   required="required" />
```

Email validation will not work if you will use `text` instead of `email` in your input type.

**Update:**

To fix the initial validation, just add `!signupForm.email.$pristine` in your `ng-show`.

**E.g.**

```
<span class="errorMessage" ng-show="signupForm.email.$error.email && !signupForm.email.$pristine" class="help-inline">Email is not valid</span> 
<span class="errorMessage" ng-show="signupForm.email.$error.required && !signupForm.email.$pristine" class="help-inline">Email is required.</span>
```

**or** you can just **wrap** the two `validation` into a `<span ng-show="!signupForm.email.$pristine"></span>`.

**E.g.**

```
<span ng-show="!signupForm.email.$pristine">
    <span class="errorMessage" ng-show="signupForm.email.$error.email" class="help-inline">Email is not valid</span> 
    <span class="errorMessage" ng-show="signupForm.email.$error.required" class="help-inline">Email is required.</span>
</span>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: When i change `type="email"` it works, but the required is not working, when i add `required`  directly inside the `<input` tag it is getting validated at initial stage itself..

Comment: How can i make the `email` field required ?

Comment: @user4989228 Just add `required="required"`.

Comment: If i put `required="required"` it starts validating initially. So, when i open the form the error messages is there by default..

Comment: @user4989228 So just add `!signupForm.email.$pristine` in your `ng-show`. **E.g.** `<span class="errorMessage"  ng-show="signupForm.email.$error.email && !signupForm.email.$pristine" class="help-inline">Email is not valid</span>`

Comment: I have just replaced my span with your example one, but it is still validating at the start itself :(

Comment: @user4989228 Can you show what your code looks like now?

Comment: You didn't include the `angularjs` library in your fiddle.

Comment: I just though of sharing you the code. Do you want me to run there ?

Comment: @user4989228 I updated your fiddle and it's working just fine. Here's the link: http://jsfiddle.net/albertonaperijr/63qmLe46/3/

Comment: @user4989228 Check if you've missed something in the code!

Comment: Yes, It works in chrome, but it is not working in the firefox Can you see this in firefox ? http://jsfiddle.net/63qmLe46/4/

Comment: @user4989228 I just tested it in firefox and it's working fine. http://jsfiddle.net/albertonaperijr/63qmLe46/5/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82205/discussion-between-user4989228-and-alberto-i-n-j).

Answer (score 0):

Check this sample form validation,

```
<form name="testForm" novalidate>
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : testForm.test.$invalid && !testForm.test.$pristine }">
<input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="test" id="txtPickUpPoint" name="test" required>
<p ng-show="testForm.test.$invalid && !testForm.test.$pristine" class="help-block">Error Message.</p>
```

It should work.